# maintaining a PIP repository

Tags: python, git, ubuntu

I am currently working on a system that requires a python installation without an internet connection available (or at least I can't assume that there is an internet connection available),

I am wondering what will be the overhead price of maintaining a PIP repository , also will be possible that such repo will also hold the system require (i.e python-dev packages and any other Ubuntu packages I may require).

Comment: What do you mean by PIP repository?

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a "pip" repository, pip is just a tool to manage packages & their dependencies. The underlying packages used are (for now) "egg" packages; pypi is a repository of these. This Q/A should answer how to setup your own: [How do you host your own egg repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519589/how-do-you-host-your-own-egg-repository)